# when importing data from excel to vb.net file open problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

When importing data from excel to vb.net desktop application, Im having "file is open" error.

Excel file is at the remote pc. Excel file must open and I have to reach anytime.

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

how about making a local copy and opening that one ?

Comment: you can't copy a file if something else has exclusive access to it.

Answer (score 0):

When Excel opens a file, it requests exclusive access. You should be able to access the same file if, when you open it, you open it in read-only mode and you allow both read sharing and write sharing.